# php script files not running on server

Tags: php

i have uploaded php files on my server but not executing when i run it on server.
but the images files are opening properly. I also checked zip, xml and other ones are working but `.php` extension files are not working.

do anyone know why this happens?

Comment: which server ? and where ?

Comment: There are a million things that could cause your problems... You need to provide more details, what PHP version is installed? What webserver are you using? etc?

Comment: Some more info would be nice: What do you see: nothing, the code itself, a 404, ...? Is PHP even installed on that server? If so, make sure you're displaying errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php.ini look for this line

```
engine = On
```

in apache modules   `php5_module` This should be ticked(on).

also

if you have mime_module ticked in the Apache Modules

Check you have the mime types set correctly in httpd.conf

This line is required

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Answer (score 0):

You must check if your host have the php module installed, if not, you'll see a download dialog when you try to access the php file.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely causes are that either:

- Your web server is not configured to support PHP
- The permissions on your files do not give the server the right to execute the PHP programmes

The former is more likely if the files are downloaded by the browser. The latter is more likely if the server presents the user with a 500 error.